# 'relationship_status' is always empty (not set)

Tags: php, facebook

I have asked for permissions like that :

```
$config = array(
'facebook' => array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx'
),
'fb_perms' => array('read_friendlists', 'friends_relationships', 'friends_photos'),
'picsize' => 'large', // avaiable options: small, normal, large, square

 );
```

but.. here

```
do
{$f1_id = $friends['data'][rand(0, NUM_FRIENDS)];
$f1_api = $facebook->api("/{$f1_id['id']}");} 
while

    ( (!isset($f1_api['relationship_status']))||(
    ( isset($f1_api['relationship_status'])&&
(
($f1_api['relationship_status']== "Married")||
($f1_api['relationship_status']== "Engaged")||
($f1_api['relationship_status']== "In a relationship")
)   )
    ));
```

make an infinite loop, because $f1_api['relationship_status'] is never set.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't publish your secret or your appId

Answer (score 0):

```
'fb_perms' => array('read_friendlists', 'friends_relationship_details', 'friends_relationships', 'friends_photos')
```

Comment: thank you for the appId and secret hiding!
I tried to add such 'friends_relationship_details' , but the same problem is still existing :(

Comment: Are you successfully getting other information like friend's photos etc?